# i don't know how to us js filter index

Tags: javascript, filter

```
const arrayRcp = ["ROCK", "Scissors", "ROCK", "Scissors"]
const user = ["par1", "par2", "par3", "par4"]
const winner = arrayRcp.filter(item => item == 'ROCK' )
const winnerUser = arrayRcp.filter(function(item,index) {...???} )
```

I want to calculate the winner's ROCK index to the winnerUser as well.
and then I don't know ...??? how to use filter index that function please help me...

As ROCK index 0 and 2 appear in arrayRcp, I want to know how to get par1 and par3 through the filter like the index of ROCK in the user.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Why is `ROCK`/`par1` always the winner? o.O

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```js
const arrayRcp = ["ROCK", "Scissors",  "ROCK", "Scissors"]
const user = ["par1", "par2", "par3", "par4"]
const winner = arrayRcp
  .map((item, index) => item === 'ROCK' && index)
  .filter(Number.isFinite)

const winnerUser = user.filter(function(_, index) {
  return this.indexOf(index) >= 0
} , winner)

console.log(winnerUser)
```